# Compare 2 list get the moving id + offset + direction

Tags: javascript, algorithm, offset, difference

I would like to compare 2 lists and get 3 variables: moving item, offset, direction.

Example 1:

Old list = 121,120,119,43,42,41,40,39,38,37

New list = 43,121,120,119,42,41,40,39,38,37

I move item 43 up to the front of list,

moving item = 43

offset = 3 (between old and new position have 3 items)

direction = +1 (as it move up)

---

Example 2

Old nids= 121,120,119,43,42,41,40,39,38,37

New nids= 121,120,119,43,41,40,39,38,37,42

I move item 42 down at the end of list,

moving item = 42

offset = 5 (between old and new position have 5 items)

direction = -1 (as it move down)

---

I am using javascript to handle it. Which algorithm I can use? Or what is the hints for me to search  in google ? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd start with a search for "compare two unordered lists in javascript."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something tested only with your examples. Perhaps it can at least provide one possible direction. (I may have left out some boundary/special cases.)

```
var a1 = [121,120,119,43,42,41,40,39,38,37],
    b1 = [43,121,120,119,42,41,40,39,38,37],
    a2 = [121,120,119,43,42,41,40,39,38,37],
    b2 = [121,120,119,43,41,40,39,38,37,42];

function f(a,b){
  var item,
      i = offset = 0,
      direction;

  while (a[i] == b[i]){
    i++;
  }

  if (a[i + 1] == b[i]){
    direction = -1;
    item = a[i];
    while (b[i] != item){
      offset++;
      i++;
    }
  } else {
    direction = 1;
    item = b[i];
    while (a[i] != item){
      offset++;
      i++;
    }
  }
  return [item,offset,direction]
}
```

Output:

```
console.log(f(a1,b1))
Array [ 43, 3, 1 ]

console.log(f(a2,b2))
Array [ 42, 5, -1 ]
```

Comment: BTW, i would like to pass old and new list to server side for comparing. It is because if the client use browser change the sort number too frequently will cause the browser crash.

Comment: http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/jlkhr and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable